# The 3 factor riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Four factors in a riddle, you see,
>   but looking at me I only count three,
>   the chest and the treasure, yes that's two,
>   but the treasure and key is only one, mind you,
>   as for zero, some aid, don't worry it's free,
>   the chest someone made, but they crafted no key.

**What is the treasure? (this is not part of the riddle, but is here to give the person solving it something to actually figure out, some people IRL have been confused and I thought this would help)**

Answer (score 6):

Is it:

> (!) exclamation mark?
>  I think it comes from 3! (three factorial).
>  There are numbers in each line, from four to zero (**four** factors, count **three**, that's **two**, only **one**, as for **zero**)
>  but there are six lines, which equals to three factorial :P (3!)

Comment: I think the line `as for zero, some aid, don't worry it's free,` is refering to the fact that `0! = 1` I guess.

Comment: That's unbelievably clever, and I really like it, but 100% not what I had in mind when I made the riddle. The key in solving the riddle is figuring out why this riddle only has 3 'factors'.

Answer (score 5):

Four factors in a riddle you see

> Riddle, Question, Tags, Answer

but looking at me I only count three

> Riddle, Question and Tags (No Answer yet)

the chest and the treasure, yes that's two

> Chest is the Riddle
> Answer is the treasure

but the treasure and key is only one

> You have to find the Key to find the Answer and solve the Riddle
> When you find the Key you know the Answer

as for zero, some aid, don't worry it's free

> Some comments are free and help to solve the Riddle

the chest someone made, but they crafted no key

> You have to find the Answer it is not written or crafted

What is the treasure?

> The Answer of the Riddle

**Another answer**
Four Factors:

> Riddle, Chest, Key, Treasure

Count Three

> Riddle, Chest, Treasure (as Key and Treasure are one)

Crafted no key

> No Lock in the Chest

The Answer

> Egg
> The White is the Chest
> The Yolk or Yellow is the Treasure
> Hens lay eggs (An egg is made from the inside out. The yolk is made first, and then wrapped in a layer of egg white, before being neatly and beautifully packaged up in an egg shell.) 
> The Three Factor might be the shell, the white and the yolk of an Egg

Comment: I really like your logic. However, the question "what is the treasure" isn't part of the riddle, it's basically a hint as to what in the world to actually solve here.

Comment: Also, in this sense, I would have already crafted the key.

Comment: I wrote another answer

Answer (score 3):

I think that the treasure is

> **a key**

Four factors in a riddle you see,

> we see a riddle, chest, key, treasure

but looking at me I only count three,
the chest and the treasure, yes that's two,
but the treasure and key is only one, mind you,

> you can only count three because the treasure is the key (you say that the treasure and the key is only one)

as for zero, some aid, don't worry it's free,

> I don't really get this one

the chest someone made, but they crafted no key

> we can see that someone made the chest but we can't see the crafted key because it is in the chest.

Comment: In a logical sense, the key _is_ the treasure, as you've guessed, but that's already established in the riddle. The trick is figuring out why there's only 3 factors in this riddle. That will help you figure out _why_ the key and the treasure are one.